# Let $X$ be the set of all even integers, and let $Y={2^n:n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Prove that $ Y\subset X$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am having trouble proving this for some reason. I think I am having trouble with the notation of the set $Y$. Can someone elaborate on how I would prove this. This is how I started.

Let $X$ be the set of all even integers. Let $Y={2^n:n\in\mathbb{N}}$. To prove that $Y\subset X$, we much show that all elements in $Y$ are also in $X$.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Think about what it means to be an even integer.  Then show that every element of Y satisfies this.

Comment: Correct: you have to prove that if $k \in Y$, then $k \in X$. But $k \in Y$ **iff** $k=2^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: I assume for you, $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$?  (Which is the opposite of the convention I'm used to.)

Comment: Yes. @DanielSchepler.. Any chance you can help me structure this proof properly?

Comment: But if $k=2^n$, then $k= 2(2^{n-1})$ and thus $k$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you must prove that $a\in X$ for all $a\in Y$. What this boils down to is proving that for all numbers $a$ that are perfect natural powers of two (so that $a\in Y$), $a$ is also an even integer (so that $a\in X$).

Since *evenness* is the property of being divisible by two, then it is trivial that all natural powers of two are even.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

Note that, for $n \geq 1$, we have $2^n = 2 \cdot 2^{n-1}$. So, any $y \in Y$ is divisible by two and is therefore even. Hence $y \in X,$ and $Y \subset X$. $\square$